# Run a script on VM before it's deleted in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

Is there a way to run bash script on a VM before it's deleted from Azure? I know you can use CustomScriptExtension for running script when VM is created or started but I couldn't find any information about launching cleanup scripts before VM is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

No, at the time of writing Azure does not support actions like this.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do, you may find it useful to subscribe to VM alerts, which can include when it is deleted. You'll have the option to call a webhook that may give you the flexibility to do what you need. Try working within the Azure portal [Monitoring Blade](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Monitoring/AzureMonitoringBrowseBlade/overview) to create your own Alert to handle this.